# Get WooCommerce specific product attribute terms sorted by "menu order"

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, taxonomy-terms

I want to sort get_the_terms by menu_order of the curent product and till now i have this code:

```
$colors='';

$terms = get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'pa_colors' );
            
foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
        $colors='<pre>'.$term->name.'</pre>';
}
echo $colors;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**There is 2 ways** to get the product attribute term names sorted by menu order *(for a defined product)*:

**1). Using `wp_get_post_terms()` function** *(WordPress way)*

The WordPress function `get_the_terms()` **doesn't allow to alter the `WP_Term_Query`**…

So instead you will use similar `wp_get_post_terms()` that allows `WP_Term_Query` tuning.

```
$taxonomy = 'pa_color'; // The taxonomy
$query_args = array(
    'fields'  => 'names',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num', 
    'meta_query' => array( array(
        'key' => 'order_' . $taxonomy, 
        'type' => 'NUMERIC'
     ) )
);

$term_names = wp_get_post_terms( get_the_ID(), $taxonomy, $query_args );

if ( ! empty( $term_names ) ) {

    // Output
    echo  '<pre>' . implode( '</pre><pre>', $term_names ) . '</pre>';
}
```

---

**2). Simply using `WC_Product` method `get_attribute()`** *(WooCommerce way)*

```
$product  = wc_get_product( get_the_ID() ); // The WC_product Object
$taxonomy = 'pa_color'; // The taxonomy

$names_string = $product->get_attribute('color');

if ( ! empty( $names_string ) ) {
    $names_array = explode( ', ', $names_string ); // Converting the string to an array of term names

    // Output
    echo  '<pre>' . implode( '</pre><pre>', $names_array ) . '</pre>';
}
```

Both ways work.